# How to run kotlin in visual studio code

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to run **.kt** file on **vscode**?
If it possible please explain it by step by step.
os: Ubuntu

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can install the "Code Runner" extension ([formulahendry.code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)) in the vscode. The extension supports running files of a number of programming languages, including kotlin. After the installation, you'll have "Run code" icon in the top right corner part of the vscode window:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it looks like a problem in your code, not a problem with the extension. Have you tried to run your code with other methods, e.g. from Intellij IDEA?